# use c# create web ActiveX to show image (without installing of .NET framework)

Tags: c#, activex

This is what I need to do.

I must create an **ActiveX** (IE add-on) in **C#** to show image(s) on client (load image(s) from Twain Scanner). 
I have made Windows Form and use System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox but it need .NET framework installed on client PC.

Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks so much.

Comment: Such an ActiveX exists already: Dynamic Web TWAIN (http://www.dynamsoft.com/Products/WebTWAIN_Overview.aspx). It requires no .NET framework on the client side. If you just need to embed the ActiveX into your website, I suggest you try this product.

Answer (score 1):

Everything written in C# requires .NET framework to run. Either the full framework or Silverlight.

If you want to write an ActiveX that is independent of the .NET Framework you have to write it in another language, such as C++ or Visual Basic 6.

I'd recommend that you really, really, really try to get out of the ActiveX requirement and instead use AJAX or Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

If you use C# to create an ActiveX control, then yes: it will require the .NET framework at the client.  You cannot change that.

If you want a non-.NET control, VB6 (though obsolete) may be simplest. AFAIK Silverlight does not offer access to scanners, so is not an option.

I also suggest, however, that ActiveX itself is already imposing a lot of demands (mainly: IE). I wonder if something like a ClickOnce client application is more appropriate. Or: just provide upload (input type="file") controls.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Marc Gravell
Do you know any opensource C++ ActiveX that able to load and show image(s) on web browser? I searched alot but i can't find any solution.

Comment: No, file uploading is generally site-specific.